# Appollonius Theorem application

Tags: geometry

In triangle ABC , if AB = AC and D is a point on BC. Prove that AB^2 - AD^2 = BD × CD. 
I tried using Pythagoras theorem but to no avail.
I heard about one Appollonius Theorem that could be used here but dont know how to.

Comment: If $D$ is an arbitrary point on $\overline{BC}$, I don't see how Appollonius is supposed to be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$. Without loss of generality, assume that $D$ lies on $\overline{MC}$. Then, using the Pythagorean Theorem a couple of times,
\begin{align*}
AB^2-AD^2 &= AC^2-AD^2 = (MC^2+AM^2)-(AM^2+MD^2) \\
&= MC^2-MD^2 = (MC+MD)(MC-MD) \\ &= (BM+MD)(MC-MD) = (BD)(DC),
\end{align*}
as required.

Comment: This is a really clean way to do it, in that $AB^2-AD^2=MC^2-MD^2$ gets you to a difference of squares whose factors have an obvious meaning.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $\angle BDA=\delta$.

\begin{align}
\triangle ABD:\quad
|AB|^2&=|AD|^2+|BD|^2-2\,|BD|\,|AD|\cos\delta
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\triangle ADC:\quad
|AC|^2
=|AB|^2&=|AD|^2+|CD|^2-2\,|CD|\,|AD|\cos(\pi-\delta)
\\
&=|AD|^2+|CD|^2+2\,|CD|\,|AD|\cos\delta
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

$\eqref{1}\cdot |CD|+\eqref{2}\cdot |BD|\Rightarrow$

\begin{align} 
|AB|^2\cdot(|BD|+|CD|)&=
|AD|^2\cdot(|BD|+|CD|)
+|CD|\cdot|BD|^2
+|BD|\cdot|CD|^2
\\
&=
(|AD|^2+|BD|\cdot|CD|)\cdot(|BD|+|CD|)
,\\
|AB|^2-|AD|^2
&=|BD|\cdot|CD|
.
\end{align}

Comment: This answer would be a lot more legible with just a simple statement about why you consider (1)*CD + (2)*BD, which is to say to cancel out the terms involving $\cos(\delta)$.

Comment: @Ian: Right, without this deep thought,
it does not give a correct answer
to the question, and costs nothing, thanks.